# how to change inline css when using mediaqueries

Tags: html, media-queries

I have an asp.net website. All pages have a master page for the design and an external css for styles.

However, some of the pages are different length so at the end of each page, on the footer div i used an inline css such as`<div id=footer style=height: 800px>`

However im also making it mobile responsive. I have an external css page for media queries. I can change all the divs and styles how I want, except when it comes to the footer it is still the height as it is set in the pages. Obviously if I remove them from the pages then the browser wouldn't get the right height. So what should I do?
If i changed the height in the responsive external css then that still wouldnt make a difference because of the inline css. So are there any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cascading rules apply. The only way to override a rule in a style attribute from a stylesheet is to use a rule with [an `!important` flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) on it.

This is a sledgehammer of a solution which only works one layer deep, so it generally best avoided.

I'd approach the problem by changing the way I handled the footers.

A quick fix would be to move the height rules into the stylesheets with classes.

A better solution would be to look at [using flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) to position the footer, or just having the footer at the end of the page instead of the end of the window.

Comment: the footers are at the end of the pages, but im not sure what you mean at the end of the window. However div classes would be a good idea.
Its just because some of the pages are longer than others, putting a set height in the master page wasn't working. So in each individual page I added an inline css. I guess classes would be the best way